# python eclipse dependency plugin - m2eclipse like

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there any eclipse plugin for python dependency management? just like what M2Eclipse does for maven project? so I can resolve all the dependencies and get ride off all the errors when I develop python using pydev.

If there is no such plugin, how do I resolve the dependencies, do I have to install the dependency modules locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you handle Python dependencies with setuptools / [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) and the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi). As an end user you will call `pip install mypackage` and the dependencies will be automatically resolved.

For development it is a common workflow that you distribute a *requirements.txt* that could be installed in a separate environment via [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). Real life example: [requirements.txt](https://github.com/ametaireau/pelican/blob/master/dev_requirements.txt) and the [developer docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/pelican/en/2.8/contribute.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only one so far I found available is PyFlakes, it does some level of dependency check and import validations.